# What is a correct way to initiate user control from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

Basically I want to create a user control in code behind, DataBind() it and then insert the control into current page

I'm currently trying this:

```
var comment = new IncidentHistoryGroupComment();
comment.LoadControl("~/Controls/IncidentHistoryGroupComment.ascx");
comment.LoadTemplate("~/Controls/IncidentHistoryGroupComment.ascx");
comment.InitializeAsUserControl(this);
comment.AttachmentActions = group.HastAttachmentActions ? group.AttachmentActions : null;
comment.Comment = group.Comment;
comment.NextStep = group.NextStep;
comment.IsInitiationStep = group.InitializationEntry != null;
comment.DataBind();
```

But still all controls inside it are null. For example i have a pane with id pnlComments and when I try to access it in IncidentHistoryGroupComment.DataBind() method I get null. I also checked Controls property to see if there is something there but Controls.Count == 0

So the question is how to correctly initialize a user control from code behind so that all controls would be assigned to their instances in IncidentHistoryGroupComment.designer.cs so I could access them easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be something like this:

```
 var comment = (IncidentHistoryGroupComment)Page.LoadControl("~/Controls/IncidentHistoryGroupComment.ascx");
```

Then you just insert into the control tree

Answer (score 2):

```
MyControl myControl = (MyControl)LoadControL("~/MyControl.ascx");
```

I changed the name of your control for readability.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is not about instantiating the user control.

In your DataBind event put this code at first line :

```
this.EnsureChildControls();
```

It instantiates all child controls if they're not istantiated. I mean it checks child controls and calls createChildControl if it's necessary.